Oracle 19c PL/SQL: Security Scan Finding - SQL Injection
I've done a search here on stackoverflow and read through some posts that are similar regarding PL/SQL SQL injection prevention, but they didn't seem to match my question specifically. This post mentions bind variables, but not parameterized variables. Are they handled the same way?
We had a security scan on our code base and the following code was flagged as a potential SQL Injection risk. I was under the impression that if I use parameterized queries that Oracle treats them similar to bind variables, and that this is a safe way to write our queries.
function get_school_id (
  p_username  varchar2
) return number is
    
  l_school_id  number;
    
begin
    
  select school_id
    into l_school_id
    from tbl_schools
   where username = p_username;
    
  return l_school_id;
    
end;

My assumption is that even if someone where to get access to this function and do:
p_username => '; delete from tbl_schools;'

It would return no rows, since it would take that string and try to find that as a 'username' in the tbl_schools table.

Is this a sql injection risk? If so, what is the best way to mitigate the above SQL?

Do parameter variables behave similar to bind variables in PL/SQL, in this regard, like I assumed? If so, is there a link someone can provide that I can show the security team? I am searching the PL/SQL docs and not finding anything, but possible I do not know the correct keyword(s).



Bind variables are used to bind a variable to a parameterised query. "Parameter variables" is not a term that is commonly used in Oracle; I think you are talking about exactly the same thing that is commonly called a "bind variable" (just using an uncommon, local, or domain-specific term).

As the linked duplicate states, no, there is not an SQL injection risk.

As an aside, you could modify the procedure to function get_school_id (p_username TBL_SCHOOLS.USERNAME%TYPE) return TBL_SCHOOLS.SCHOOL_ID%TYPE is l_school_id TBL_SCHOOLS.SCHOOL_ID%TYPE; begin ... so that you explicitly state that the values are the same type as the columns used (and if the column data-types are ever modified then you do not need to modify the code).

thanks @MTO for confirming. I wasn't sure if bind variables referred to the :BIND_VARIABLE format only (with semi colon). So thanks for clarification.

External bind variables are defined using :variable_name and are defined somewhere outside the local scope. PL/SQL variables are defined as variable_name and may be used as bind variables in SQL statements within the PL/SQL scope of that variable without the preceding : - they are still variables that are being bound to the (parameterised) SQL statement (i.e. bind variables).
